# Get List of custom user class inherit from ApplicationUser in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I created a class that inherits from `ApplicationUser` like This:

```
public class Company : ApplicationUser
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public String Boss { get; set; }
    public string Slogan{ get; set; }
}
```

EF will add a Discriminator column to `dbo.AspNetUsers`

I get a property from `Company` class like this:

```
Company cm = (Company)db.Users.Find(id);
```

That works fine but how can I get a list of `Company` users (i.e. where `Discriminator == "Company"`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`OfType<...>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) extension:

```
var companyUsers = db.Users.OfType<Company>();
```

Doing that will run SQL something like this:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].Id,
    [Extent1].Column2.
    --etc
FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Discriminator] = Company'
```

Comment: Don't forget you can upvote/accept answers that have helped you.

Comment: i try to upvote but  show me this meesage:
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post Score

Comment: Haha it's OK, I'm just giving you some general advice. You should be able to accept answers though, you will get 2 rep for accepting too.